# How to show list of custom objects in a page in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I want to create a page in Drupal 6 where I can show list of restaurants.When a user clicks on any restaurant page, I should be redirected to Restaurant details page.

For this :
1.) I created a new content type called "Restaurant" with some fields.
2.) Created 3-4 content items for Restaurant( Restaurant1, Restaurant2, Restaurant3)
3.) Created view called: RestaurantList, Added Fields for it. Then added Page Display and gave the path for it http://website/Restaurants

Now, when I browse to Restaurants page, I only get labels of my fields but no values. How can I get the values but not the labels? Also, I want to go to the RestaurantDetails page. How can that be achieved?

Thanks,
Rashmi

Answer (score 0):

Well if I were to set up a page view this is how I would set it up:

Filters:

- Node type - Restaurants
- Node published - Yes

Fields

- Node title

  - check the option `Link this field to it's node`
  - leave the `Label:` field empty
  - check option `Hide if empty`

And if your view style is a `HTML list`, for extra you can go to `Row style options` and check the option: `Hide empty fields`

Make sure you click `Preview` to see if you get any values. If you don't then there's something wrong with the view settings, most probably the filters which are to restrictive. Start with something loose, like Node type - Restaurants.